# How can I attach an event to just one div block at a time in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, onchange

This code block takes an array of questions, parses them into their own div blocks, and displays them.

**ISSUE:** Upon clicking the completed checkbox, a text box should appear for users to type notes into.The issue is that when I click the completed checkbox for one div block, I check it for each and every other div block too which prompts a text box to come up for every other div block.

ANY SUGGESTIONS?

My code is as follows:

```
class Questions extends Component {

state = {};

constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = { checked: false };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange() {
    this.setState({
      checked: !this.state.checked
  })
}


/*
 * This method takes an array of strings and generates them in a nicely formatted div block for the user to view
*/
renderQuestions(){
    const hidden = this.state.checked ? '' : 'hidden';

    const questions = ['Criterion 1 - Have you taken all your required courses ?', '2 - Have you taken all your required credits?',
    '3 - What is your current schedule like?', '4 - Do your laboratories meet proper safety protocols?',
    '5 - Are you required to take a senior design course?', '6 - ', '7 - ', '8 -'];

    const q = questions.map((questionsToPrint, index) =>
    <div key={'questions' + index}>
    <div id='rectanglePadding'>  {/* this indents the rectang */}
        <span id='blockStyling'>
            <span style={{textAlign: "left", paddingLeft: "20px"}}>
            <a id='textStyling'>{questionsToPrint}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
            <p id="lineBr" />
            <input type="checkbox" checked={ this.state.checked } onChange={ this.handleChange }/> <label>Completed </label><span id="whiteSpace"> </span>
            <input type="checkbox" /> <label>Concern </label><span id="whiteSpace"> </span>
            <input type="checkbox" /> <label>Weakness </label><span id="whiteSpace"> </span>
            <input type="checkbox" /> <label>Deficiency </label><span id="whiteSpace"> </span>
            <input type="checkbox" /> <label>Strength </label><span id="whiteSpace"> </span>
            </span>
            <br />
           <a className = { hidden } style={{float: "left"}}>Notes</a><textarea className={ hidden } style={{marginLeft : "20px", float:"left"}}> </textarea>
        </span> 
    </div>
    <br />
    </div> 
    );

    return (
        <div>{q}</div>
    );
}

render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <br />
        <div>
        <nav id='navBar' className="navbar navbar-expand-sm">
            <ul className="navbar-nav">
            <li><Link to={'/questions'} className="nav-link"><button id='btn'>Pre-Visit</button></Link></li>
            <li><Link to={'/qday0'} className="nav-link"><button id='btn'>Day 0</button></Link></li>
            <li><Link to={'/qday1'} className="nav-link"><button id='btn'>Day 1</button></Link></li>
            <li><Link to={'/exit'} className="nav-link"><button id='btn'>Exit</button></Link></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        </div>
        <br /><br />
        <h1 style={{textDecoration: "underline", textAlign: "center"}}>Questions: Pre-Visit</h1>
        {this.renderQuestions()}
    </div>
    );
}
}
```

[image: See screenshot of the issue here]

Comment: Can multiple checkboxes be checked?

Comment: Yes, the PO wants it to be that way @Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need some way to maintain the `checked` state for each element in your map. Consider the following, which has a `checked` object that can potentially have key for each element in your array.

Note that this solution uses the element index to key the state object. This may or may not be good depending on your use case (it would be better if there was a true unique key associated with each element of the array).

Also note that I have changed `hidden` into a function that takes the index and determines whether elements are hidden on a case-by-case basis.

```
class Something extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = { checked: {} };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(i) {
    this.setState({
      checked: {
        ...this.state.checked,
        [i]: !this.state.checked[i]
      }
    });
  }

  /*
   * This method takes an array of strings and generates them in a nicely formatted div block for the user to view
   */
  renderQuestions() {
    const hidden = (i) => this.state.checked[i] ? undefined : "hidden";

    const questions = [
      "Criterion 1 - Have you taken all your required courses ?",
      "2 - Have you taken all your required credits?",
      "3 - What is your current schedule like?",
      "4 - Do your laboratories meet proper safety protocols?",
      "5 - Are you required to take a senior design course?",
      "6 - ",
      "7 - ",
      "8 -"
    ];

    const q = questions.map((questionsToPrint, index) => (
      <div key={"questions" + index}>
        <div id="rectanglePadding">
          {" "}
          {/* this indents the rectang */}
          <span id="blockStyling">
            <span style={{ textAlign: "left", paddingLeft: "20px" }}>
              <a id="textStyling">{questionsToPrint}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
              <p id="lineBr" />
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                checked={this.state.checked[index] || false}
                onChange={() => this.handleChange(index)}
              />{" "}
              <label>Completed </label>
              <span id="whiteSpace"> </span>
              <input type="checkbox" /> <label>Concern </label>
              <span id="whiteSpace"> </span>
              <input type="checkbox" /> <label>Weakness </label>
              <span id="whiteSpace"> </span>
              <input type="checkbox" /> <label>Deficiency </label>
              <span id="whiteSpace"> </span>
              <input type="checkbox" /> <label>Strength </label>
              <span id="whiteSpace"> </span>
            </span>
            <br />
            <a className={hidden(index)} style={{ float: "left" }}>
              Notes
            </a>
            <textarea
              className={hidden(index)}
              style={{ marginLeft: "20px", float: "left" }}
            >
              {" "}
            </textarea>
          </span>
        </div>
        <br />
      </div>
    ));

    return <div>{q}</div>;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <br />
        <div>
          <nav id="navBar" className="navbar navbar-expand-sm">
            <ul className="navbar-nav">
              <li>
                <Link to={"/questions"} className="nav-link">
                  <button id="btn">Pre-Visit</button>
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to={"/qday0"} className="nav-link">
                  <button id="btn">Day 0</button>
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to={"/qday1"} className="nav-link">
                  <button id="btn">Day 1</button>
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to={"/exit"} className="nav-link">
                  <button id="btn">Exit</button>
                </Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <h1 style={{ textDecoration: "underline", textAlign: "center" }}>
          Questions: Pre-Visit
        </h1>
        {this.renderQuestions()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That fixed the issue, but now the text area won't appear :(

Comment: Did you definitely update the textarea code with `className={hidden(index)}`?

Comment: Yeah, I used your code snippet exactly how you pasted it

Comment: @coder_coder123 I recreated your code here and it seems to work correctly with my changes: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-ptolemy-hendg

Comment: One last thing, what's the purpose of the '{" "}' lines in your code snippet? I've never seen them before

Comment: Those are useful when you have to enforce an actual space between content on different lines.